# Python pandas series xticks not showing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a following `pandas.Series`:

```
>>> x.index
>>> Index(['00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30',
       '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', '05:41', '05:50', '06:00', '06:10',
       '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:01', '09:30',
       '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '12:31', '13:00',
       '13:01', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '14:31', '15:00', '15:30', '15:31',
       '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '17:31', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00',
       '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00',
       '23:30', 'NaT'],
      dtype='object', name='sStart')
```

When I try to plot it, it looks good, but I am missing xticklabels:

[image]

Unfortunately I am not allowed to provide you data to test. So is there a way to make those hours and minutes appear on the x axis?

Comment: They are strings. Strings do not have labels in pandas due to [this bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22334). You might convert them to datetimes.

Comment: Well, I did: `x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index).strftime('%H:%M')
ax = x.plot()` and the result is the same

Comment: Well, `.strftime` converts a datetime to a string. Hence the result from the bug report.

Comment: Okay, but then how can I get them as date? And with proper amount? (the length is like 50something, and on this graph I see only 6)

Comment: Cause I did this: `ax = x.plot()
x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index).time
ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(x.index))))
ax.set_xticklabels(x.index)` and the result is: https://imgur.com/r1OtE15

Comment: What happens if you use `x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index); ax = x.plot()`?

Comment: This happens: https://imgur.com/a/wD1FyF0

Comment: Yep, that's the expected output.

Comment: It's not unfortunately. I don't need dates (in fact putting them there is invalid, cuz its not the data captured from 1 day, its the mean of the data from like 5 years, grouped by hours)

Comment: Then you need to use matplotlib for plotting (`plt.plot(x,y)`) and a locator and formatter from `matplotlib.dates`.